# Meeting point of turning wheels with rear wheels

Tags: manufacturing-engineering, wheels, car

I was watching [this](https://youtu.be/em1O8mz7sF0?t=242) video about how steering on a vehicle. It states:

> If you track the meeting point of the left and right wheels, you can see that the meeting point **always** lies on the rear wheel line.

I have a few questions about this:

1. If the car is longer or shorter or wider or thinner, the meeting point of the left and right wheels **would not** be on the rear wheel line. How then is the steering setup such that the meeting point is **always** in line with the rear wheels? Is there a process for determining it?
   Below is a photo of the meeting point not aligning with the rear wheels:
   [image: Common point]
2. Why does the meeting point need to be in line with the rear wheels? Would the wheels skip or slip along otherwise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wikipedia explains it fairly well.

[image]

*Figure 1. Image source: [Ackermann steering geometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ackermann_steering_geometry).*

> A simple approximation to perfect Ackermann steering geometry may be generated by moving the steering pivot points inward so as to lie on a line drawn between the steering kingpins and the centre of the rear axle. The steering pivot points are joined by a rigid bar called the tie rod which can also be part of the steering mechanism, in the form of a rack and pinion for instance. With perfect Ackermann, at any angle of steering, the centre point of all of the circles traced by all wheels will lie at a common point. Note that this may be difficult to arrange in practice with simple linkages, and designers are advised to draw or analyse their steering systems over the full range of steering angles.

If the vehicle is stretched then the steering pivot points will move out and the angle of the solid arms (dark brown in the image) will change to suit.

You might enjoy the [Project Binky steering setup](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ob-FUF0Sh_E). This is episode 11 of (currently) 31 half-hour episodes and is a fantastic series.

Answer (score 2):

The meeting point of the angled front wheels will always intersect the line from the rear wheels.

All that happens as the vehicle changes dimension is that the turning circle becomes larger, or smaller. The Volvo series (140, 240 etc) of cars were known for being easy to manoeuvre due to the angle the front wheels would turn to.

There will always be a meeting point and it defines how the car turns and also helps set up things like the Ackermann steering angle: that the inner wheel of the turn is at a greater angle than the outer to reduce scrubbing.

One point to consider is that the meeting point should be the same distance on either side of the car, one thing that is checked (by good body shops) when dealing with chassis damage after an accident. Some have driven cars or vans that feel like they are "crabbing" down the road...

There are some good books about this, one to start you off is Fundamentals of Vehicle Technology by Hillier & Pittuck.

Edit: One of our questions at college during the apprenticeship was to calculate the angle of the inner wheel, given the wheelbase, track and turning angle of the outer wheel. A scale drawing was all that was needed. Mark the points of the wheelbase and track, extend the centreline of the rear wheels, locate to point where the outer wheel intersects and then draw the line for the inner wheel and measure the angle. Plus or minus 1 degree was allowed for the result so you had to be careful with the scale and quality of drawing.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @solar-mike. I'm struggling to understand how the meeting point angled front wheels would always intersect with the rear wheels. For example, if the length of the vehicle shown in the video was extended a couple of metres, the meeting point would not be in line with the rear wheels. Could you please clarify how it would always meet? I may be missing something.

Comment: The centre line for the rear wheels is extended as far as is necessary, defining the turning circle - why some cars are poor at parking etc.

Comment: I've added an image to clarify what I mean. If the body of the vehicle is extended, the meeting point of the left and right wheels does not align with the rear wheels. Would this mean that you would have to adjust the turning angle of the outer wheel right, as you have mentioned in your edit or something else as well?

Comment: If you have to adjust the turning angle of the outer wheel, how is this achieved? Do you have to extend the length of the tie rod?

Comment: That diagram shows what I have explained, if the wheelbase is increased, then the lines from the front wheels will still intersect... Changing the angle of the front wheels means turning the steering wheel, changing the angles between the two front wheels means adjusting the linkage between them.

Comment: Thanks mate. I understand that the lines from the front wheels will still intersect no matter the length of the vehicle, however what I do not understand is the importance of the common point between both front wheels and the rear wheels lines. By extending the length of the chassis, the front wheels will not intersect with the rear wheel line at the same place, therefore I am confused by what the importance of the common point is between the front and rear lines.

Comment: If you change the wheelbase, then you are dealing with a new situation, so that will have a new intersect point. That new point defines things like turning circle, but we are now back to what i put in my answer anyway.

Comment: So just to clarify, by ensuring the common point is shared between the front and rear wheel lines, the turning circle is minimised, and this is achieved by adjusting the linkage between them? Does this mean the steering on limousines is compromised as the steering is no longer appropriate for the length of the vehicle?

Comment: I'm not sure, but it appears that a key factor is being overlooked in this discussion. If a dimension of the vehicle is changed, the geometry of the steering mechanism also has to be changed. It will not necessarily be as simple as an adjustment of the tie rods or any other specific component.

Comment: @fred_dot_u so you mean camber or kpi?

Comment: I don't know that camber would change with wheelbase change and I'm not sure of the kpi abbreviation. With a new wheelbase, the entire ackerman solution becomes different with respect to linkage, pittman arm, etc., not just tie rod adjustment. The intersection of the front wheel normals will intersect the rear axle line for a new wheelbase, but not for all angles of turn unless the overall geometry is changed.

Comment: @fred_dot_u, thanks for the additional perspective. The question has been addressed in the latest answer.